# Why is virtual WndProc not called?

Tags: c++, winapi

Here's what I have so far... Even though I instantiate a Window (subclass of WindowBase), I am getting the error that a pure virtual function is trying to be called.  Basically, my program is trying to call WindowBase::WndProc instead of Window::WndProc.

#### WINDOWBASE.H

```
#ifndef WINDOWBASE_H_
#define WINDOWBASE_H_

#include <Windows.h>

class WindowBase {
public:
  WindowBase(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow);
  ~WindowBase();

  void Show();

protected:
  virtual LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam) = 0;

private:
  static LRESULT CALLBACK WndRouter(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam);

  HWND hWnd;
  int nCmdShow;
};

#endif /* WINDOWBASE_H_ */
```

#### WINDOWBASE.CPP

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "WindowBase.h"
#include <tchar.h>

WindowBase::WindowBase(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow) {

  this->nCmdShow = nCmdShow;

  WNDCLASS wcex;

  //wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
  wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndRouter;
  wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
  wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
  wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
  wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
  wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
  wcex.lpszMenuName = _T("TestMenu");
  wcex.lpszClassName = _T("TestWindow");
  //wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

  if (!RegisterClass(&wcex)) {
    MessageBox(NULL,  
               "Call to RegisterClassEx failed!",
               "Win32 Guided Tour",
               NULL);
  }

  hWnd = CreateWindow(_T("TestWindow"), _T("TestWindow"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 100, NULL, NULL, NULL, (void*)this);

  if (!hWnd){
      MessageBox(NULL,
                 "Call to CreateWindow failed!",
                 "Win32 Guided Tour",
                 NULL);
  }
}

WindowBase::~WindowBase() {
}

void WindowBase::Show() {
  ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
  UpdateWindow(hWnd);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowBase::WndRouter(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam) {
  WindowBase* base = NULL;

  if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE) {
    base = reinterpret_cast<WindowBase*>(((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams);
    SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)base);
  } else {
    base = reinterpret_cast<WindowBase*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
  }

  if (!base)
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

  return base->WndProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); // GETS TO HERE, BUT TRIES TO
    // CALL WindowBase::WndProc, INSTEAD OF Window::WndProc
}
```

#### WINDOW.H

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H_
#define WINDOW_H_

#include "windowbase.h"

class Window : public WindowBase {
public:
  Window(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow);
  ~Window();

protected:
  virtual LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};

#endif /* WINDOW_H_ */
```

Comment: ...and you definition of Window is...

Comment: You should have a virtual destructor.

Comment: Added. And that still won't fix my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call `CreateWindow` in your `WindowBase` constructor, you start to receive messages from there.

If you create your `Window` object, it's own constructor have to call the `WindowBase` constructor. During that point, the `Window` object is not yet came to existence, and so its virtual functions aren't yet available (they will refer a not yet constructed Window ...).

Your design have also a number of other pitfalls:  Think about the scope and lifetime of every component: some of them are used before constructed, other destroyed when still needed.

It's not that easy to wrap an OOP C API (like WIn32) into another OOP language (like C++) that have a notion of "Object" and "scope" the t don't match the one WIN32 thinks about. Take care of both of them, or you can easily get cod that looks working, but used in a more wider context (more window than just one) risk to behave not as expected.

Comment: So what's wrong with creating a protected Create() method in WindowBase that gets called from Window?  I did this and it seems to be working.

Comment: Yes, that works. But it is no more C++ canonical OOP (you are in fact doing a 2 phase construction, not). But don't worry: the problem has essentially no solution in the canonical CPP OOP universe.